# QImage comparison based on cache keys

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

CacheKey method of QImage returns not really a plain hash of image. Does anyone know, what the upper 32 bits mean? And can I really ignore them when comparing two images? (Compare only the lower 32 bits?)

---

For illustration only, this code reading the same image multiple times (yet storing them in different QImage objects):

```
printf("%llx\n",QImage("image.png").cacheKey());
printf("%llx\n",QImage("image.png").cacheKey());
printf("%llx\n",QImage("image.png").cacheKey());
```

returns this?

```
144300000002
144400000002
144500000002
```

or this? (seems like the upper 32 bits depend on current memory position)

```
140800000002
140900000002
140a00000002
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't use any part of the `cacheKey` to compare image content, it only exists to make sure an image hasn't changed since the last `cacheKey` value was taken. It identifies the buffer and changes whenever any non-const function of the `QImage` is called.

But as the name of the `cacheKey` property implies, you can use it as a key for a `QCache<qint64, QByteArray>` where you would store the actual hash of the image that you would only recalculate with `QCryptographicHash` only if the image was changed (= only if it isn't already in the cache).

Also `QImage` doesn't use a cache like `QPixmap` for reading an image, so reading 3 times the same image file will allocate 3 distinct buffers, each time with a different `cacheKey`. To avoid calculating the hashes each time, you should take a look at the source code of the `QPixmap::load` function.

Comment: As I understand it correctly, only way of comparing two QImages is to save them to QByteArray, compute a hash by QCryptographicHash and then compare these hashes. I am not really sure if comparing them pixel by pixel will not be faster...

Comment: This isn't the only way (and you can skip the `QByteArray` saving, by passing the result of `QImage::constBits` to `QCryptographicHash::addData`), it depends on how often you need to compare `QImage`s. If you only need to compare 2 images, you can use the `==` operator, if you need to compare 1 images against 10 others , the hashing might be faster, but it any case, you have to benchmark each method (but don't use `QImage::pixel()` because it is quite slow).

Answer (score 2):

The upper 32 bit depend on nothing, but the 32 bit of the previous image. It is a serial number, which in incremented with each new QImage.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source for [QImage](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/gui/image/qimage.cpp) :

```
qint64 QImage::cacheKey() const
{
    if (!d)
        return 0;
    else
        return (((qint64) d->ser_no) << 32) | ((qint64) d->detach_no);
}
```

looks like the upper 32 bits are d->ser_no which is initialized with QImageData:

```
QBasicAtomicInt qimage_serial_number = Q_BASIC_ATOMIC_INITIALIZER(1);

QImageData::QImageData()
    : ref(0), width(0), height(0), depth(0), nbytes(0), data(0),
#ifdef QT3_SUPPORT
      jumptable(0),
#endif
      format(QImage::Format_ARGB32), bytes_per_line(0),
      ser_no(qimage_serial_number.fetchAndAddRelaxed(1)),
      detach_no(0),
      dpmx(qt_defaultDpiX() * 100 / qreal(2.54)),
      dpmy(qt_defaultDpiY() * 100 / qreal(2.54)),
      offset(0, 0), own_data(true), ro_data(false), has_alpha_clut(false),
      is_cached(false), paintEngine(0)
{
}
```

And it looks like QBasicAtomicInt is an atomic reference counter ([see here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/36042-QBasicAtomicInt-ref%28%29-what-the-hell-is-this)). So it looks like every new image will have a different upper 32 bits in the cachekey value unless you copy it rather than create it anew.